# HAProxy SSL and Heartbleed Exploit

Tags: openssl, haproxy, heartbleed-bug

With the openSSL Heartbleed exploit, I'm assuming that compiling HAproxy with the openSSL package will mean it is vulnerable. What would be the process to update? Update openSSL and recompile HAProxy?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software versions, administration and patching. Server Fault has quite a few questions on the topic: https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/heartbleed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using one of the affected OpenSSL versions (1.0.1 through 1.0.1f), update to version 1.0.1g where the exploit has been addressed.

http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/720951